# In the kubernetes cluster, the host cannot access the SVC IP

Tags: kubernetes, kube-proxy

This is my cluster environment：

```
service cluster ip cidr:10.254.0.0/16
pod ip cidr: 172.30.0.0/16
kube-proxy: ipvs mode
flannel : vxlan
```

kubectl version

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.4", GitCommit:"5ca598b4ba5abb89bb773071ce452e33fb66339d", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-06-06T08:13:03Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.4", GitCommit:"5ca598b4ba5abb89bb773071ce452e33fb66339d", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-06-06T08:00:59Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

The results I expected:
I can access the SVC IP normally from the kubernetes master.
On the master host, I have deployed kube-proxy and flannel.

All components of my kubernetes cluster are deployed via the release binaries.

---

I have deployed my cluster normally, and in most cases, it can provide services externally.
I have deployed an nginx server，My screenshot:

[nginx server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omDbZ.png)

```
Service IP: 10.254.126.228
Pod IP: 172.30.21.3
```

When I access the pod IP (172.30.21.3) directly on the kubernetes master host, it can be accessed normally.

My screenshot:
[http request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXm80.png)

But when I access the service IP, the access timeout occurs.

My screenshot:
[Access SVC IP time out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3zEw.png)

This will only happen when the SVC IP is requested on the host outside the container. If I am in the container, I can access the SVC IP normally.

My screenshot:
[in the container http request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdyBD.png)

This is my list of ipvs rules:
[ipvs rule list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73q2X.png)

I used tcpdump to listen to the flannel.1 NIC and docker0 NIC on the nginx pod node host and found the following problems:

When I access the pod IP directly at the kubernetes master host, the flannel NIC on my master host will send the packet to the node host flannel NIC , then forward it to the docker0 NIC, and finally the pod IP. At the same time, pod IP will respond to my request and everything is normal.
But when I access the SVC IP on the kubernetes master host, I found that the NIC that sent the packet changed to eth0 instead of using the flannel NIC, so the flannel NIC on the node host directly dropped the request and did not continue forwarding to docker0.

I realize that this may be a problem with policy-based routing. If I forward the request with the destination 10.254 to the correct gateway, can I solve this problem?

But this should have a more standard solution. Can anyone help me?

(I am sorry that my English is not very good...）

Comment: Do u see any errors when you create the service in the kube-controller-manager?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I did the test, when I created SVC, kube-controller-manager did not report an error.
My controller-manager log level is 4
The following is the log output of creating SVC. You can see that SVC can be created normally.
LOG:
Endpoints_controller.go:512] Update endpoints for default/dc-yapi, ready: 1 not ready: 0
Finished syncing service "default/dc-yapi" endpoints. (10.723997ms)

Answer (score 0):

It seems your svc CIDR  has intersection with host CIDR

Comment: Thank you for your attention to this issue.
When I change the service CIDR to: 172.30.0.0/16, there is still this problem. And I am sure that 10.254.0.0/16 is unreachable on my host.

Comment: Can u post your routing table here

Answer (score 0):

Kernel IP routing table

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

0.0.0.0         10.125.232.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0

10.125.232.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0

172.30.1.0      172.30.1.0      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 flannel.1

172.30.3.0      172.30.3.0      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 flannel.1

172.30.21.0     172.30.21.0     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 flannel.1

172.30.81.0     172.30.81.0     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 flannel.1

172.30.92.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 docker0

172.30.94.0     172.30.94.0     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 flannel.1

Here is my routing table.

@白栋天